# Karate - Exception raises for invalid jsonpath

Tags: karate

I have a Json response like below. The difference here is my Json body has a number as the parent node.

```
    def response =
"""
{
  "22388043":[
    {
      "firstName":"Romin",
      "lastName":"Irani",
      "phoneNumber":"408-1234567",
      "emailAddress":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
"""
```

I want to return the **mobileNumber** attribute value from the response body. In this scenario I don't have that attribute in my response. So here I want to get a null value.

So when I use *** def mobile = $.22388043[0].mobileNumber**, I'm getting below error.

**No results for path: $['22388043'][0]['mobileNumber']**

Please advise on this.

Comment: I'm not seeing any attribute called mobileNumber, I think you meant phoneNumber?

Comment: In this response I don't have the mobileNumber attribute. When that attribute is present the value is returning. The issue that I'm having is when the attribute is not present I get this error instead of getting a null value

Comment: * def mobileNum = karate.get("$.22388043[0].mobileNumber")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate does give you a way to get the values of JSON keys.

Hopefully this example answers all your other questions as well:

```
* def response =
"""
{
  "22388043":[
    {
      "firstName":"Romin",
      "lastName":"Irani",
      "phoneNumber":"408-1234567",
      "emailAddress":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
"""
* def id = karate.keysOf(response)[0]
* match id == '22388043'
* def person = response[id][0]
* match person contains { firstName: 'Romin', lastName: 'Irani' }
* match person.mobileNumber == '#notpresent'
```